# How do i get specific data from SQLITE DATABASE and display it in TextView

Tags: android, database, sqlite

1. How do i get 1 specific row from the database (by id for example)

   > Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE _id = 1",
   >   null);

??

2. how do i display it in edittext ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Cursor myCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE _id = 1", null);
String myEditTextValue =  myCursor.getString(*ColumnIndexHere*);

EditText myEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.*EditTextIdHere*);
myEditText.setText(myEditTextValue );
```

However pls note the best practice in Android is to use Content Providers. To find out more check out this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKjFfcFelrI
and this
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

EDIT: as Android changes, new best practice is to use Room which is part of the Jetpack Library.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room